# Resize div circle

Tags: html, css, resize, geometry, window-resize

I'm trying to make a div table with cells. Inside the cells I'd like to put another div which has circle shape. The problem which I've trying to solve is that I would like that when I resize the window of the browser, the div circle adapts to it and keeps the proportion.

As you can see in the images when I reduce the size of the window the size of the circle it's ok, but when the window it's in normal size the cirrcle it's too big and I don't know how to limit it.

https://gyazo.com/ebd2f44131dcc2e84b9d0e5cdaf12aed

reduced window

https://gyazo.com/6b8889f2d6c59b74bc7036061cf62627
https://gyazo.com/afb97aa2093e7331ae100420e1bac9c9

stylesheet.css

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.Table{
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    //border:solid;/////////////////////////////////////
   // width: 100%;
   // height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
     table-layout: fixed;

     width:80%;
    height:80%;
}


.Row{
    display: table-row;

}

.Cell{
    display: table-cell;
   // border: 5px;
    border:solid;
  //  border-color: black;
   // border-radius: 25px;
    //background-color: blue;
        width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
}

.circle {

  width: 100%;

    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4679BD; 

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estils.css">

    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="Table">
            <div class="Row">
             <div class="Cell"   >eeee</div>
                <div class="Cell"   >aaaaa</div>  
                <div class="Cell"   >iiii</div>     
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell"   >eeee</div>
                <div class="Cell"   >aaaaa</div>  
                <div class="Cell"   >iiii</div>  
            </div>
               <div class="Row">
                   <div class="Cell"   >
                       <div class="circle"   ></div>
                   </div> 
                   <div class="Cell"   >
                       <div class="circle"   ></div>
                   </div> 
                   <div class="Cell"   >
                       <div class="circle"   ></div>
                   </div> 
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `media-queries` for that.

```
@media (min-width: 1000px)
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

would do the trick. But the `@media (max-width: 1000px)` depends on the browser window's width.